# Can Watson trigger a dialog based on 12 digits pattern?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I try to display a message that contains the number inserted in the question, for example when user inserts a number of 12 digits I want to display that 12 digits and a text. 
Until now:

- I created an Entity with pattern (/d{12}) named @ticket_number
  [image: Entity definition]
- An Intent named #myTicket that has as example @ticket_number 
  [image: intent def]
- Dialog that triggers when #myTicket | @ticket_number and has on context TicketNumer "`<?@ticket_number.literal?>`" and display a message as follows "Do you want to get info for ticket $ticketnumber ?". 
  [image: Dialog]

The problem is that when I try it the Intent result is irrelevant, the message looks ok but I need to match the Intent. What could I do?

[image: Error]

Comment: Is there any related intent? What does the dialog node look for? And note that you need to capture the entity literal, e.g. @ticket_numer.literal

Comment: What do you mean by "related" intent ? Yes I captured it with "<?@ticket_number.literal?>" it gets the number and displays it in my message but the problem is that it is triggered by entity, I think, and the intent is not recognized. If I delete the or ( |@ticket_number) part from Dialog it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: In the dialog node to what event does it react? You can configure it to just react to the entity OR an intent

Comment: I wrote in question it reacts at #myTicket | @ticket_number but I would like it to react only to the intent.

Comment: But the intent needs to be recognized. If only the number is entered, likely it is not because it is an entity

Comment: So it is not ok to have an example for an intent that is made only from an Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the IBM [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-intents) 
it is not yet possible to use pattern entity in Intents.

> Currently, you can only directly reference synonym entities that you
>   define (pattern values are ignored). You cannot use system entities.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share a picture of your node? There is no need that you match the intent; as indicating the ticket number alone, should not be an intent itself, but the entity. I'd remove the `#myTicket |` part of the node. And the condition should not include an OR; otherwise, if #myTicket triggers the node, and there is no ticket number, the response would fail.

Comment: I use the intent too because Watson should trigger the same dialog for other inputs written in that intent. I thought it should be useful to create an example in the intent that only contains the entity.